# Terraform/AWS - Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to deploy the following resource while cycling through my subnets.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id                   = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block               = element(var.public_subnets_cidr, count.index)
  availability_zone        = element(var.`your text`availability_zones_public, count.index)
  count                    = length(var.public_subnets_cidr)
```

However, I'm receiving the following error.

```
│ Error: Error in function call

│ on vpc/main.tf line 33, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":

│ 33: cidr_block = element(var.private_subnets_cidr, count.index)

│ │ while calling element(list, index)

│ │ count.index is 30

││ var.private_subnets_cidr is "[\"192.168.4.0/24\",\"192.168.5.0/24\",\"192.168.6.0/24\"]"

│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.`
```

Any idea why this is? From the look of things, this should be fine?

```
    public_subnets_cidr          =  ["192.168.0.0/24", "192.168.1.0/24", "192.168.2.0/24"]
    private_subnets_cidr         =  ["192.168.4.0/24", "192.168.5.0/24", "192.168.6.0/24"]
    availability_zones_public    =  ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
    availability_zones_private   =  ["us-east-1d", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1f"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear, `var.private_subnets_cidr` is `"[\"192.168.4.0/24\",\"192.168.5.0/24\",\"192.168.6.0/24\"]"` which is **literal string**, not a list `["192.168.4.0/24", "192.168.5.0/24", "192.168.6.0/24"]`.

You have to check your variables, probably you are overwriting `private_subnets_cidr` somewhere. Make sure you use a `list`, not a `string` as value for `private_subnets_cidr`.

Comment: @Trainington Answer updated.

Comment: Looks like that was it. I was passing the variable in but not defining the type and I think it was defaulting to a string. Thanks.